# Can reparameterizing the parameters for DEoptim improve convergence: whether/how to do it?

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

DEoptim is [described as](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEoptim/index.html)

> DEoptim implements the Differential Evolution algorithm for global optimization of a real-valued function of a real-valued parameter vector as described in Mullen et al. (2011) <[doi:10.18637/jss.v040.i06](https://doi.org/10.18637%2Fjss.v040.i06)>

I am wondering about the following case: if we have parameters that live on vastly different scales from one another (e.g., one parameter takes on values between .001 and .00001; another that takes on values between 1000 and 100000), would it help convergence to reparameterize the search space for the parameters such that the search space for the reparameterized parameters is the same (e.g., that both of the aforementioned parameters are rescaled such that they take on values between 0 and 1), given how the mutations occur from one iteration to the next?

Any recommendations on how to speed convergence (beyond increasing NP and lowering F) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have rewritten your question to make it more approachable as a general statistics problem and less like a programming problem. You can undo the changes if you like.

Comment: Thank you - this looks good to me!

Comment: I am not familiar with a differential evolution algorithm, but is this problem not very similar to other optimization problems where different scales of parameters may play a role?

Comment: Yes, it would because the parameters are encoded as floating point numbers, and it can take many iterations to match a floating point exponent to the correct order of magnitude needed to begin to converge on a solution.

Comment: Sextus, I think this could partially be a more general optimization problem, but partially specific to genetic algorithms, and even more specifically, to how DEoptim evolves the population from one iteration to the next. I am second guessing myself because parameter elements within the parameter vector are not exchanged with one another.  Each element is a function of that element from other candidate parameter vectors. So it is more about changing the scale of each element.